# Combine logical vectors in list using logical OR

Tags: r, list, boolean, boolean-logic

### Question

How do I effectively combine logical vectors across the list using elementwise comparisons with logical `OR` (`|`). The result should be a logical vector of same length as the input vectors. If *any* of the input values is `TRUE`, the result is `TRUE`, else the result is `FALSE`.

### Example

I have a list opts with a set of logical vectors of the same length.

```
> str(opts)
List of 5
 $ option1: logi [1:608247] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ option2: logi [1:608247] FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  ...
 $ option3: logi [1:608247] FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE ...
 $ option4: logi [1:608247] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

and I want this as a result:

```
logi [1:608247] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
```

Thus, the first value of the result, `FALSE`, is because the are *no* `TRUE` in the first position across all vectors of the list. The second value of the result, `TRUE`, is because the are two (*at least one*, `any`) `TRUE` in the second position of the vectors.

I am fine with changing my datastructure to be a `matrix` or `data.frame` or something else if it is better I just get this from a `lapply`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

How about Reduce:

```
Reduce("&", opts)
Reduce("|", opts)
```

Comment: +1 This is the cleanest solution, and according to my benchmarking, also the fastest.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know Reduce existed. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have tried to obtain the `sum` of the cases (to evaluate which is more frequent TRUE vs FALSE) and the proper function wasn't `"sum"`, it was `"+"`...Just in case any other come here with the same question.

Comment: As far as I am aware, such special functions (such as `&`, `|` or `+`) work when enclosed in backticks ( ` ) and not in quotation marks ( " )

Comment: @Matteo, if you are calling the _object_, then yes you need backticks. However, if you are referring to the name of the object, as is the case above, then you would use quotes (single or double). 

eg. `\`&\`(var1, var2)` would be correct, since we are calling the object whose name is `"&"`. The object in this case is a function.

Answer (score 9):

If all the lists are the same length, you can cast it to a data frame, and then use `any`:

```
apply(data.frame(opts),1,any)
```

Edit: while I thought this might be fast because it avoids `cbind`, it turns out that this is the slowest by far of the three solutions, according to my benchmarking:

```
set.seed(123)
opts = as.list(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10000, replace=TRUE), nrow=1000)))

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Reduce("|",opts),rowSums(do.call(cbind, opts)) > 0,
               apply(as.data.frame(opts),1,any))


Unit: microseconds
                               expr      min        lq   median        uq
                  Reduce("|", opts)   99.200  101.0780  106.596  110.3725
  rowSums(do.call(cbind, opts)) > 0  209.326  211.9665  217.329  224.0505
 apply(as.data.frame(opts), 1, any) 4130.429 4245.7380 4308.054 4438.2485
     max neval
  120.63   100
  237.19   100
 6949.19   100
```

Comment: Judging by the microbenchmark package (`microbenchmark(apply(data.frame(opts),1,any))`): this is by *far* the fastest solution. (This makes sense, since `any` will short circuit on finding the first TRUE value).

Comment: Hmm, when I benchmark it, this solution seems to be by far the slowest.

Comment: What size `opts` are you using? And what composition of TRUE and FALSE? (I'm using the approach in my post below)

Comment: I'll add the output to my solution in a sec.

Comment: Ah: I'm afraid I missed the switch in the output from milliseconds to microseconds- quite silly of me! It looks like my solution is the fastest then. ETA: Or looks like Reduce, indeed.

Comment: Yours and `Reduce` are pretty close, but mine is much slower.

Comment: Oddly, on my machine I'm getting my expression as (marginally) faster than Reduce. But agreed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
(rowSums(do.call(cbind, opts)) > 0)
```

For example:

```
opts = as.list(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10000, replace=TRUE), nrow=1000)))
str(opts)
```

`do.call(cbind, opts)` creates a 1000x10 matrix of TRUEs and FALSEs:

```
dim(do.call(cbind, opts))
# [1] 1000   10
head(do.call(cbind, opts))
#        V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#[5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

`rowSums` will create a vector showing the number of TRUE values in each row: in any case where that row sum is greater than 0, logical or returns TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions with pmap() and any(), and some additional benchmarking**

I also like to use `purrr`s `pmap`, as a general approach to rowwise operations.
pmap is definitely not the fastest as shown in the benchmarking below (not vectorized as Reduce() or reduce() or rowSums()), but i find it very versatile and consistent.
You can use this with `any` in this case, which is faster and, to me, more intuitive than nested/sequential `|`.

```
library(purrr)
opts%>%pmap_lgl(., any)
```

`purrr`s version of `Reduce()`, `reduce()`, is similar to @Ricardo Saporta`s answer, but keeps the consistency of syntax we see in purrr:

```
library(purrr)
opts%>%reduce(., `|`)
```

I have done a little benchmarking too.

```
microbenchmark(Reduce("|",opts),
               Reduce(any, opts),
               rowSums(do.call(cbind, opts)) > 0,
               apply(as.data.frame(opts),1,any),
               pmap_lgl(opts, any),
               reduce(opts, any),
               reduce(opts, `|`)
               )

Unit: microseconds
                               expr      min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
                  Reduce("|", opts)   40.303    59.3935    87.71092    77.5005   107.3490    461.228   100
                  Reduce(any, opts)    8.576    15.6625    29.48404    23.6775    31.9965    185.628   100
  rowSums(do.call(cbind, opts)) > 0   70.458    94.8565   133.39620   130.3765   154.3775    675.701   100
 apply(as.data.frame(opts), 1, any) 2580.162  3642.5935  4848.82291  4725.7095  5476.0935  19805.711   100
                pmap_lgl(opts, any) 7420.634 11071.3780 14972.01035 13362.0735 14820.2190 164536.018   100
                  reduce(opts, any)  229.924   388.0765   515.31035   524.9820   629.1945   1052.248   100
                  reduce(opts, `|`)  277.262   485.9855   688.35137   699.9830   790.6440   1717.872   100
```

The benchmarking clearly shows Reduce() is the fastest `Reduce>rowSums+cbind>reduce>apply>pmap_lgl` and that `any>"|"`