# Parallel 'or' operation on many logical vectors

Tags: r, parallel-processing, logical-operators

In R, I have a number of logical vectors, or varying number (ie sometimes `1`, sometimes `n` vectors), they are guaranteed to be ALL of the same length, I need to produce a single vector of the same length as the input vectors, where each element is to be `TRUE` if any of the vectors at the same element index are `TRUE`, else `FALSE`.

I am wondering if there is a builtin operation, or simpler method, to achieve what I want. Below is what I have so far, for 3 vectors.

```
set.seed(1) #For reproducability
o = c(T,F)
l = 10
A = sample(o,l,replace=T)
B = sample(o,l,replace=T)
C = sample(o,l,replace=T)
fun = function(...) apply(do.call(cbind,args = list(...)),1,any)
fun(A,B,C) ##Produces Desired Result
```

Comment: `matrixStats::rowAnys(cbind(A, B, C))`

Comment: @Khashaa Thanks. added to the benchmarking.

Comment: Related: [Combine logical vectors in list using logical OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250544/combine-logical-vectors-in-list-using-logical-or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `|`

```
Reduce(`|`, list(A, B, C))
```

Or with `rowSums`

```
rowSums(cbind(A,B,C))!=0
```

If there are only 3 vectors, a compact option would be

```
!!(A+B+C)
```

Comment: I cant guarantee the number of vectors, the quantity is only known at runtime, therefore, the first 2 will work, the last will not.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton  Thanks for the reply.  I will leave that as such for others having 3 or 4 vectors.

Comment: Heres another option: `!!(Reduce('+',lapply(LETTERS[1:3],get)))`

Comment: @NicholasHamilton  Instead of `get`, you can use `Reduce('|', mget(LETTERS[1:3]))`

Comment: Anyone feel like benchmarking all these variations?

Comment: @NicholasHamilton  You can post the benchmarks as another post as I have to go now

Answer (score 3):

Here are some benchmarks for the various methods listed above, using a larger vector as suggested by @Roland.

```
set.seed(1) #For reproducability
o = c(T,F)
l = 1000000
A = sample(o,l,replace=T)
B = sample(o,l,replace=T)
C = sample(o,l,replace=T)

library(microbenchmark)
f.0 = function() apply(do.call(cbind,args = list(A,B,C)),1,any)
f.a = function() Reduce(`|`, list(A, B, C))
f.b = function() rowSums(cbind(A,B,C))!=0
f.c = function() !!(A+B+C)
f.d = function() !!(Reduce('+',lapply(LETTERS[1:3],get)))
f.e = function() Reduce('|', mget(LETTERS[1:3]))
f.f = function() matrixStats::rowAnys(cbind(A, B, C))
microbenchmark(f.0,f.a,f.b,f.c,f.d,f.e,f.f,times=10000)
```

Which produces the following result on my macbook air w/ I7 processor.

```
Unit: nanoseconds
 expr min lq     mean median  uq   max neval
  f.0  39 57 118.4767     78 123 23685 10000
  f.a  43 61 119.5952     85 130 63523 10000
  f.b  38 53 100.5252     77 120 27199 10000
  f.c  39 55 100.9784     77 121 17656 10000
  f.d  37 52 111.5138     75 118 78505 10000
  f.e  39 57 113.1461     80 125 16111 10000
  f.f  35 52 105.9245     74 117 19995 10000
```

So they all seem pretty close to each other and my initial method wasn't the slowest, but, also wasn't the fastest...

Comment: May I suggest to use the neat `microbenchmark` package?

Comment: Yep ok. Fair enough. Pants a different picture.

Comment: It's an excellent idea to do benchmarks when you get several answers.

Comment: @Roland, cheers, I have modified the code to test vectors of length 1e6