# Combine several boolean variables in a data frame in R using a logical or

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean

Combine several boolean variables in a data frame using a logical or
I have a data frame with several boolean variables that I am trying to combine.

Here is an example dataset:

```
     temp1 temp2 temp3
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

I want to add a fourth variable "temp4" that is TRUE if either temp1 OR temp2 OR temp3 are TRUE. I have tried this:

```
temp$temp3<-any(temp1,temp2)
```

But it coerces it into a list and creates a strange output.

The closest I have found is this: [Combine logical vectors in list using logical or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250544/combine-logical-vectors-in-list-using-logical-or)

But this is for a list, not a data frame, and I'm not familiar with lists and can't figure out how to apply it to my problem.

Thanks

Comment: `Reduce(\`|\`, temp)` assuming that `temp` is actually a `data.frame` and not a `matrix` as it looks like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Use an apply loop.  E.g.:

```
temp4 <- apply(temp, 1, any)
cbind(temp, temp4)
```

Comment: Great, this works. What if I want to select the columns that are used? Say I want a variable temp5 that is TRUE if either temp1 or temp3 are TRUE.